# Bug: POI picture heremap api differences between api code and apikey

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I try to get image of the POI with heremap api?

When I try by apicode I have the medias retrieved:

[image]

When I try with the url for apiKey and I do not change anything other parameter it retrieves no medias.

[image]

Is it a bug?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please share the value of id parameter you have tried to test this?

Comment: The id is: s-Yz1zcG9ydHMtZmFjaWxpdHktdmVudWU7aWQ9MjUwdTA5dHUtODhhNjcwNDcyYzc0NGVkNTkzM2JiZjU2MDY2ZGI1OGQ7bGF0PTQ4Ljg0NTQ5O2xvbj0yLjMyNTY2O249Q2x1YitNZWQrR3ltO25sYXQ9NDguODQ1NTI7bmxvbj0yLjMyNTUzO3BoPSUyQjMzMTQ1NDQyNDM1O2g9NDQwOTM0

Comment: Hello. Did you find any issues?

Comment: Hi. I still see the bug. Can you please fix it? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the actual URLs you used? It's really hard to read the screen shots. You can hide the key of course. Also note you appear to be using the older version of the lookup API.